# VBA programming

Tags: vba, excel

VBA apply column filter without resetting existing filter on the same column. (Amend a column filter)

I have a below macro which applies column filter correctly however when the same code gets executed second time to apply another filter on the same column, the existing filter is removed and new filter gets applied.

Can someone please help me to fix this thing where I am able multiple filter on a single column?

```
Sheet.Range.AutoFilter Field:= 10, Criteria:="Auto"
```

Now I am to apply further filter to include "Banks" filter in the same column while retaining the auto filter.

```
Sheet.Range.AutoFilter Field:= 10, Criteria:="Banks"
```

After having done this, the column should filter with 2 conditions (Auto and Banks)

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use an array to [autofilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-autofilter-method-excel) for multiple criteria in one column:

```
.AutoFilter Field:= 10, Criteria1:=Array("Auto", "Banks")
```

Comment: Thank you, array works for me.
Just out of curiosity, using my original code, is there a parameter that needs to go so that existing filters are retained and new gets applied along side it?

Comment: @TauseefShaikh I don't know of any way. For the same column you will always have to apply the complete filter with autofilter. If this answer solved your question please mark it as solution, so everyone knows that this is solved.

Comment: Array also exhibit similar behaviour for me :(

.AutoFilter Field:= 10, Criteria1:=Array("Auto", "Banks")

Filter gets applied on Banks only and not both Auto and Banks.

It is not advisable for me to use Criteria1 and Criteria2 option as my filter criteria is getting generated at run time and criteria may increase or decrease depending of user configuration.

Comment: @TauseefShaikh Well, then please edit your original question and show your actual and relevant code (not only one line) and a screenshot of your data.